# Trying to set up Github Passport2 Strategy with React/express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport-github2

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong I've followed the documentation and it looks like I set up everything correctly but it just doesn't want to grant me the access token and redirect me! Do I need to redirect out of react-router to the auth/github route?

Any help guiding me in the right direction and pointing out my errors will be much appreciated!

````
const GitHubStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// My client and secret are in the empty strings.

const GITHUB_CLIENT_ID = '';
const GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET = '';
const GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL = '/auth/github/callback';

passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  cb(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, cb) {
  cb(null, obj);
});

passport.use(
  new GitHubStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL,
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      console.log(accessToken, refreshToken, profile);
      return cb(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

module.exports = GitHubStrategy;

const router = require('express').Router();
const db = require('../models');

router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  db.User.find({
    username: { $regex: new RegExp(req.query.q, 'i') },
  }).then(() => console.log(req.params.q));
});



router.get(
  callbackURL,
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function (req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/home');
  }
);

module.exports = router;




const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('./config/GithubPassport2');
const apiRoutes = require('./routes/apiRoutes');
const app = express();
const db = require('./models');
const cors = require('cors');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

// Define middleware here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

app.use(
  session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.sessions());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // allow to server to accept request from different origin
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true, // allow session cookie from browser to pass through
  })
);

// Use apiRoutes
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

//  Send every request to the React app
// Define any API routes before this runs
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'));
});

// Start the API server
db.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
  app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`  ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`);
  });
});



import React from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function SignIn({ icon }) {
  return (
    <section className='container-fluid'>
      <section className='row'>
        <section className='col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3' />
        <form>
          <div className='form-group'></div>
          <Link
            className={icon}
            to='/auth/github'
            style={{ paddingLeft: '40px' }}>
            &nbsp; Sign in with Github
          </Link>
        </form>
      </section>
    </section>
  );
}
SignIn.defaultProps = {
  icon: 'fab fa-github',
};

export default SignIn;```
````